# Magento 2: Call to a member function setState() on array

Tags: magento2, sales-order, controllers, order-status

I want to change the **order Status programmatically** but when I run the `function realTest()` as I mentioned below then it gives me an error `Call to a member function setState() on array` in the below function it mentions line number **5**. I also tried function `use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;` in place of other class as I mentioned in my code but in both scenarios, it gives me the same **error** also when I tried the array to `print_r($orderState)` then it returns me **null array**.

```
use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
public function realTest(){
        try{
            $orderId = 000256076;
            // obtain the order with the order ID
            $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderId);
            $orderState = \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
            $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
            $this->_orderRepository->save($order);
            return true;
        } catch (\Exception $e){
            echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
            // add some logging here
            return false;
        }

    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you check the $order by printing it?

Comment: yeah I mention it in my question. I also `print_r($order)` it reutrns me null array

Comment: yeah thats the point your code is correct but the order with the respected order id doesn't exist, so how can you apply the status on null, try to test it with the existing order id

Comment: this maybe I'm not passing the correct value value of the *orderId*???

Comment: yes try to pass the correct order id and then test and let me know

Comment: I tried that as well but same issue

Comment: It seems ridiculous that you are passing the correct order id but still getting the null array

Comment: Hello @AsadKhan,
I am facing the same issue, the original code is working fine, but when we pass the data from Test\Unit it is giving error of "Error: Call to a member function setState() on null", 
did you found any solution for the same in Test\Unit Class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a try to below code.

> With Increment Id

```
$incrementId = 000256076;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
$orderState = \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
$order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
$order->save();
```

> With Order Id

```
$orderId = 1271; //check if the order exists with this id or not
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
$orderState = \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
$order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
$order->save();
```

Comment: Sir I also tried this as well then it gives me an error `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on null`

Comment: It seems like the issue is with the $orderId, is your order id exists in admin?

Comment: Yes Sir it exists....

Comment: For confirmation, Order ID or Order increment number?

Comment: Sir check the question I update the question also upload the image from where I get the Order ID

Comment: This is the increment id of the order my friend, please share the view link of the order with me.

Comment: Sorry Sir I didn't get it properly where is the view link?? only I have order is this place that I mentioned in the image

Comment: `http://localhost/annalou/admin_z3jvbp/sales/order/view/order_id/1271/key/c0c4b310a0090fb81dde1bb8b92fde4aab2987b92d33310fce38da94df15ac84/`

Comment: I've updated my code for the increment id, you can check,

Also, please change $orderId = 1271; in your code to make it work. (order_id/1271 in the URL given by you)

Comment: Sir Kindly check the Error I already updated the `$orderId` but also the same error

Comment: have you tried my code once in your controller?

Comment: Sir One last question... on every single status its changes but in case of when the order status is completed then it cannot be changed...

Comment: Yes, I've faced same problem. It is only possible on the database level. 
We can not update the status from complete to processing within Magento.

Comment: else from every single status we can change this?? like from cancel to processing and many more?

Comment: Yes, you can change them.

Answer (score 2):

**Try This :-**

```
/**Magento/Sales/Model/Order $salesOrder**/
$orderId = 12345;
$statusCode = \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING;

$order = $this->salesOrder->load($orderId);
$order->setState($order->getState())->setStatus($statusCode);
$order->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to good but 
Once try to use following code

```
use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
public function realTest(){
        try{
            $orderId = 1271;
            // obtain the order with the order ID
            $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderId);
            $orderState = \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
            $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
            $this->_orderRepository->save($order);
            return true;
        } catch (\Exception $e){
            echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
            // add some logging here
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Still the same issue...

Comment: Change your order id with real order id which exist in magento.

Comment: `000256076` it is not the order id. It is order increment id. Click on this order in admin grid then you can get the order id from URL

Comment: `http://localhost/annalou/admin_z3jvbp/sales/order/view/order_id/1271/key/c0c4b310a0090fb81dde1bb8b92fde4aab2987b92d33310fce38da94df15ac84/` this url???

Comment: Order id : `1271`

Comment: Use this order id in your code please.

Comment: I hope it will help you.

Comment: I tried this as well but not working

Comment: I updated the Question kindly check the error image

Comment: Now are you able to get order data when printing `$order`?

Comment: NO... But I got the solution from one another code

Comment: I think you didn't define this `$this->_orderRepository` in your `constructor` method

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this check

```
use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
    public function realTest(){
            try{
                $orderId = 256076;
                // obtain the order with the order ID
                $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderId);
                if(!empty($order->getData()){
                   $orderState = \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
                   $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
                   $this->_orderRepository->save($order);
                   return true;
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e){
                echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
                // add some logging here
                return false;
            }

        }
```